# How to restriction React native app uninstall

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I m developing a parental control app using react-native. basically this app does some basic parental control function. Is any way to restrict app uninstall in android. because this has some requirement to restrict app uninstall without parent permissions.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you cannot prevent an app from being uninstalled.

**Alternative idea/suggestion:** Check if you could send a mail/notification to the parent when the app is uninstalled. Since a parental control app will always be running you could implement a mechanism where it sends the parent a notification whenever the app is turned off/removed.

Answer (score 3):

For Android:

You cannot make any app your device admin or stop it from getting uninstalled, But the app should have the feature or permission to be a device admin in order to achieve what you need.

As you can see in the list of apps in **settings>security>device administrator.**

Just check on the forums, how to get the admin permission/privileges for your reactive native apps.